# link url not working in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, hyperlink, base-url

I am just starting and implementing template in codeigniter 3.1
after login when i click on any side menu then it doesn't work. if i tried to open in new window then its automatically logout & redirect to login page.
my view is following.

```
<li class="active treeview">
      <a href="<?php echo base_url()."user/admin"; ?>">
        <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span>
        <span class="pull-right-container">
          <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
        </span>
      </a>          
    </li>
```

my controller user have function name admin have following code.

```
function admin(){
$user_login=array(
'user_email'=>$this->input->post('user_email'),
'user_password'=>md5($this->input->post('user_password'))
);
$data=$this->user_model->login_user($user_login['user_email'],$user_login['user_password']);
  if($data)
  {          
    $this->session->set_userdata('user_id',$data['user_id']);
    $this->load->view('template/header');
    $this->load->view('template/sidemenu');
    $this->load->view('body');
    $this->load->view('template/footer');
  }
  else{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg', 'Wrong Credentials...');
    $this->load->view("login.php");
  }


}
```

Comment: Have you set your `base_url` in the config file ?

Comment: Tip: In codeigniter you don't need to use .php when loading views `$this->load->view("login");`

Comment: Check if in `../approot/application/config/config.php`, `$config['base_url']` is setted and in `../../application/config/autoload.php` `$autoload['helper'] = array('url')`

Answer (score 1):

is this 'base_url()."user/admin'  your dashboard link?? because in your user controller there is login or sign in code.

Comment: 'base_url()."user/admin'
yes above code is dashboard link. after login people can see this.

Comment: okay but its calling admin function, in which login code is there, so it will redirect you on login page everytime when you click on this link <li class="active treeview">
      <a href="<?php echo base_url()."user/admin"; ?>">
        <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span>
        <span class="pull-right-container">
          <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
        </span>
      </a>          
    </li>

Comment: but when i logged in then it should be redirect to dashboard. not in login page because i have already logged in

Comment: than write one condition that is
if($data)
  {          
    $this->session->set_userdata('user_id',$data['user_id']);
    $this->load->view('template/header');
    $this->load->view('template/sidemenu');
    $this->load->view('body');
    $this->load->view('template/footer');
  } else if(!empty($this->session->userdata('user_id')){ redirect(base_url().'dashboard'); }else{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error_msg', 'Wrong Credentials...');
    $this->load->view("login.php");
  }

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Open application > config > autoload.php

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```